# Composer ругается на версию php

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Хочу установить хлебные крошки diglactic/laravel-breadcrumbs на проект Laravel(8.75) на сайт - ispmanager стоит PHP FastCGI (Apache) 7.4.33
при установке выдает ошибку в консоле показывает 5.4.16, узнавал у хостинга обновить нельзя, как можно решить проблему? прикладываю скрины

```
[![командная строка][1]][1]
```

[image: ошибка]
[image: версия php в консоли]
[image: версия php в isp]

Comment: Тебе же пишут что у тебя в композере рассчёт на пыху 7.3, а стоИт у тебя 5.4.   Обнови пыху.

Comment: потыкайте настройки в isp, наверняка меняется. 7.4 у вас там видимо для апача стоит, для консоли видимо отдельно переключается. Либо запускать его надо с указанием полного пути, а-ля `/var/bin/php74`

Comment: версию консоли на рег ру не обновить и не поменять

Answer (score 0):

вот это помогло установить:
/opt/php/7.4/bin/php-cgi /ПУТЬ ДО композера/composer.phar require diglactic/laravel-breadcrumbs